# Visual Studio crashes after typing

Tags: visual-studio

I haven't used Visual Studio for the past year because of this problem. When I type anything in Visual Studio 2020, 2019, or 2017, the program freezes up to 5 seconds later, and then crashes, leaving no error.
After I crashed in VS 2019 I did some digging and found the errors in AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_39fc2ef8\ActivityLog.xml

I found these 4 errors:

```
Still unable to load MEF component DLL: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.CppSvc.Internal, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CodeAnalysis\Microsoft.VisualStudio.CodeAnalysis.VCPlugin.dll
Still unable to load MEF component DLL: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Windows.Simulator.Client, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2019\community\common7\ide\commonextensions\platform\diagnosticshub\Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.VisualStudio.Package.dll
Still unable to load MEF component DLL: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.LiveShare.LanguageServices.16.3, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2019\community\common7\ide\commonextensions\microsoft\managedlanguages\vbcsharp\languageservices\Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.LiveShare.dll
Still unable to load MEF component DLL: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.LiveShare.LanguageServices.16.3, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
          C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\PYTHON\LIVESHARE\Microsoft.PythonTools.LiveShare.dll
```

System information:
Windows 10 Pro
Visual Studio 16.6.1

Comment: Never seen that. Reinstall, reboot, retry.

Comment: Please also tell something about your environment. Windows verson, if you've installed Microsoft .NET libraries before, anything that can be relevant. Virus scanner, stuff like this.

Comment: If you installed MSBuild in the GAC by any chance then see [this ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/952614/after-update-from-vs-2019-1645-to-vs-2019-165-gett.html).